# Laravel Blade limit the character of @yield result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, yield, substr

I have multiple views that has a common @section that will be displayed in a layout file. And i have to limit the number of characters that @yield returns.

```
// layout.blade.php
...
<meta property="og:title" content="@yield('og_title', 'Default Value')" />
...
```

```
// sample.blade.php
...
@section('og_title', $page->og_title)
...
```

Although the sample is simple enough to understand, each og_title @section has its own post processing (if... else...)

For now, what I'm doing is to add substr to each and every og_title @section and repeat it to all views. The problem is, when the character limit changes (e.g. 60 to 75), I also have to change it to each view.

```
// sample.blade.php
...
@section('og_title', substr($page->meta_title, 0, 60))
...
```

Is there a way to limit the number of characters that @yield returns?
Similar to:

```
// layout.blade.php
...
<meta property="og:title" content="@yield('og_title', 'Default Value', $limit??)" />
...
```

I also tried adding substr to @yeild but it returns an error:

```
// layout.blade.php
...
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ substr(@yield('og_title', 'Default Value'), 0, 60) }}" />
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of skirmishing with google, I found a somewhat "hacky" solution, to use the underlying function for yield then apply substr to it

```
// layout.blade.php
...
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ substr(e($__env->yieldContent('title', 'Default Value')), 0, 60) }}" />
...
```